# ajaxStop not firing

Tags: jquery, ajax

I'm not able to get `ajaxStop` to fire on my page.  Am I missing something obvious here???

```
var photoArray = [];
var urls = [URL1, URL2] //these are proper URLS in the complete script
_.each(urls, function(url) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'jsonp',
        error: function(x,y,z) {
            console.log(x,y,z);
        },
        success: instagrab
    });
});

$(document).ajaxStop(function() {
    console.log("ajaxstop");
    $(this).unbind('ajaxStop');
}); 
function instagrab(data) {
    _.each(data.data, function(val){
        var tagged = $.inArray(tag, val.tags);
        if (tagged !== -1) {
            photoArray.push(val);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It should be `$.each`. You have an underscore.

Comment: I have underscore.js loaded. Sorry, should have mentioned that. The ajax calls work fine. the problem is that i'm not seeing the `console.log` statement.

Comment: Are you sure? http://jsfiddle.net/TfhhX/ (I had to change the underscores to `$`) and output looks good.